# Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file, warning message

Tags: xml, joomla

I am getting waring message, JInstaller: :Install: Cannot find Joomla XML setup file

Joomla version is 3.0.

Tried changing  to , 3.0 to 3.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE install PUBLIC "-//Joomla! 3.0//DTD template 1.0//EN"
    "http://www.joomla.org/xml/dtd/1.6/template-install.dtd">
    <extension version="3.0" type="template" client="site">
        <name>aj_dynamic</name>
        <creationDate>25 September 2012</creationDate>
        272103_1_EnDan Rahmel
    </author>
    <authorEmail>drahmel@joomlajumpstart.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>http://www.joomlajumpstart.com</authorUrl>
    <copyright>Copyright (c)2012-2013 Dan Rahmel.</copyright>
    <license>GNU GPL</license>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <description>Responsive template created in the book
        Advanced Joomla!</description>
    <files>
        <filename>index.php</filename>
        <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
    </files>
    <positions>
        <config>
            <fields name="params"></fields>
        </config>
    </extension>
    <position>debug</position>
    <position>position-0</position>
    </positions>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your XML file is a little muddled up. It has missing tags and tags in incorrect places.

It should be as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<extension version="3.0" type="template" method="upgrade" client="site">
    <name>aj_dynamic</name>
    <creationDate>25 September 2012</creationDate>
    <author>272103_1_EnDan Rahmel</author>
    <authorEmail>drahmel@joomlajumpstart.com</authorEmail>
    <authorUrl>http://www.joomlajumpstart.com</authorUrl>
    <copyright>Copyright (c)2012-2013 Dan Rahmel.</copyright>
    <license>GNU GPL</license>
    <version>3.0</version>
    <description>Responsive template created in the book Advanced Joomla!</description>

    <files>
        <filename module="mod_aj_dynamic">mod_aj_dynamic.php</filename>
        <filename>templateDetails.xml</filename>
    </files>

    <positions>
        <position>debug</position>
        <position>position-0</position>
    </positions>

    <config>
        <fields name="params">
            <fieldset name="basic">
                 <field name="params1" label="Param 1" default="" />
                 <field name="params2" label="Param 2" default="" />
            </fieldset>
        </fields>
    </config>
</extension>
```

Note that I have changed **index.php** to **mod_aj_dynamic.php**. You also need to apply this name change to the actual file too.